# Best practice for collectd and graphite

Tags: graphite, collectd

What is the best way to send metrics from multiple servers to graphite (will then use Grafana to view graphite data):

1) Install collectd daemon on all servers and send to a collectd central server.  Configure collectd server to send data to graphite.

2) Install collectd daemon on each all servers and configure to send metrics directly to graphite server.

Thank you